# Form values not being displayed in html

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm working on dynamic table, where I don't know the number of rows in advance. The problem is that the calculate `total` doesn't show up in html even though its value is saved in `component` object.

Here is my html code:

```
<table style="overflow-x: auto;display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
    <thead>
        <tr class='tableHeader'>
            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22" class="pr-4">Name</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Price</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Loan Term</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Quantity</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Deposit</td>
                <td fxFlex="15" class="pr-4">Total</td>
            </div>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of loanProductForm.get('products').controls; let i = index">
            <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                <td fxFlex="22">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="productId" [id]="'productId' + i" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                {{product.name}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' (keyup)="onPriceChange($event)" matInput formControlName="price"
                            [id]="'price' + i" name="" placeholder="Price" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                        <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" [id]="'loanTermId' + i" required>
                            <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                            </mat-option>
                        </mat-select>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" [id]="'quantity' + i" matInput name="" id=""
                            placeholder="Quantity" required>

                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" [id]="'deposit' + i" matInput name="" id=""
                            placeholder="Deposit" required>
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>
                <td fxFlex="15">
                    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                        <mat-label>Total </mat-label>
                        <input type='number' formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" id=""
                            placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold" required>
                        <!-- <input disabled type='number' [(ngModel)]="totalValue" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" id="" placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold" required> -->
                    </mat-form-field>
                </td>

            </div>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td fxFlex="10">
                <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                    <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100'
                        (click)='addProductButtonClick()'>Add
                        <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and here is component code

```
this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      products: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.addProductFormGroup()
      ])
    });



 addProductButtonClick(): void {

    (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(this.addProductFormGroup());
    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value)

  }


addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: [0, Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [0, Validators.required],
      deposit: [0, Validators.required],
      total: [0, Validators.required],
    });
  }
```

I'm trying this method but this doesn't show the value in html even though it saves fine in my `object`
formula to calculate total value is `(price*quantity) - deposit =total`

```
this.loanProductForm.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
  values.products.forEach(product => {
    product.total = (product.quantity * product.price) - product.deposit
  })

  console.log('Updated values of form are: ', values.products)
})
```

Image for better understanding:

[image]

Comment: Can you create stackblitz that will be easy to debug

Comment: Sorry but my application uses angular material and much back-end api data, I tried but it was not working in stackblitz
I added the image for better undertanding

Comment: In which method you have written this `this.loanProductForm.valueChanges` ? In `onPriceChange()` method?

Comment: please share your form variables (i.e. loanProductForm), also I don't see where you set your formarray form and attach to the form.

Comment: It seems like you have added ngModel property to the total column. Can you try to change the value of `totalValue` variable while you are subscribe to valueChanges?

Comment: I've added @MustafaKunwa
@JP_ No I've removed the ngModel from my `total` column in html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
this.loanProductForm.valueChanges.subscribe((values) => {
  (this.loanProductForm.get('products') as FormArray).controls.forEach(group => {
    let total =  (group.get('quantity').value * group.get('price').value) - group.get('deposit').value ;
    group.get('total').setValue(total) ;

  })
})
```

Comment: this even doesn't let me compile the code, it gives a red underline error in VS code `Property 'controls' does not  exist on type 'AbstractControl'`

Comment: still not working with the error
`ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.get current [as current] (zone-evergreen.js:66)
    at scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone (zone-evergreen.js:1107)`

Comment: Please see this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dax42n

Comment: wOw, thank you so much.
I just figured out I was not using pipe (this statement `.pipe(debounceTime(200))` )
as I just added this to my code, it started working. as per my little knowledge, it should work even without this too. but any way.. I'm not concerned about this as long as my code is working fine
Thanks a lot once again.

Comment: One more thing, How do I automatically display the `price` and `loanTerm` of product as soon as the user select the product from drop-down list.
Please

Answer (score 0):

When assigning values to formcontrol, we need to use setValue(). This might work -

```
product.total.setValue((product.quantity * product.price) - product.deposit);
```

Comment: sorry this gives me error as
`ERROR TypeError: product.total.setValue is not a function`

Comment: How about this - `product.controls['total'].setValue((product.quantity * product.price) - product.deposit);`  . In the image posted, 0 in the total column indicates it's showing the default value. Maybe it's not setting the value properly into the formcontrol.

Comment: Now it gives the following error `Cannot read property 'total' of undefined`

Comment: @LingVu any other solution you know please